# Generating sound similar to a xylophone in C++ with any frequency

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

Im trying to make a program that plays and reads music. I already have everything done but the method of generating the tone is horrible and sounds bad. Theres a clicking sound every time it makes a sound, multiple sounds cant play at once, and its just a pure tone. Is it possible to make it generate a sound similar to hitting a xylophone or and non pure tone that actually sounds good enough to make music with?

```
const double amplitude = 0.5;  // Amplitude between 0.0 and 1.0
const double twoPi = 2.0 * 3.14159265358979323846;
sf::SoundBuffer buffer;
sf::Int16* samples = nullptr;
sf::Sound sound;
const int sampleRate = 44100;
const int numSamples = static_cast<int>(duration * sampleRate);

void playTone(const double frequency, const double duration, const bool pause) {
    samples = new sf::Int16[numSamples];
    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
        double time = static_cast<double>(i) / sampleRate;
        samples[i] = static_cast<sf::Int16>(amplitude * SHRT_MAX * sin(frequency * twoPi * time));
    }

    buffer.loadFromSamples(samples, numSamples, 1, sampleRate);
    sound.setBuffer(buffer);

    sound.play();

    if (pause) {
        sf::sleep(sf::seconds(duration));
    }

    delete[] samples;
}
```

Right now I just have a boring function that uses the c++ SFML library to generate a tone. I barely even understand how it works. Ive tried using threads to play multiple at once but nothing has worked. Playing multiple at once isnt even the most important. I mainly want a more realistic and beautiful sound, like a xylophone. Id be fine with using a different library if it can make the sound better.